# lcmm package: gridsearch cl returning Error: " in get(name, envir = envir) : first argument has length > 1"

Tags: r, package, syntax-error

I am trying to use the `gridsearch()` function from the lcmm package for R. I am using an MacBook M2 2023 running Ventura 13.5 in R ver. 4.3.1 and lcmm version 2.0.2. This error has been replicated using CentOS running R version 4.2.2 and the same lcmm version.

When running this function, using either an integer or the object output from `makeCluster()` function from the parallel R package, I get the error:

`Error in get(name, envir = envir) : first argument has length > 1`.